# How many processes where created during one minute?

Tags: python, linux, process

I would like to know how many processes the Linux kernel created during
a period of time.

Usually during one minute.

My background: If too many processes got created during a minute, then there is something wrong. Most of our legacy code base was moved from shell to python, but sometimes there are still some shell scripts which are slow because they a lot of processes.

I would like to create a graph from this number. Then I would like to check on which host and why so many processes got created.

I want to implement this with Python.

Answers how to read this from /proc or /sys would be great.

It would be nice if the solution works for the wrap around which happens if pid_max gets reached.

The limit (maximum number of pids) is `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`. [The manual](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) says:

> `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` (since Linux 2.5.34)
>
> This file specifies the value at which **PIDs wrap around** (i.e., the
>   value in this file is one greater than the maximum PID).  The default
>   value for this file, `32768`, results in the same range of PIDs as on
>   earlier kernels

Comment: Would checking spawned processes every few secs is a working solution?

Comment: @OrDinari why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check `/proc/stat`, there is a `processes`
field, counts numbers of fork since boot, [doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

```
$ grep processes /proc/stat
processes 81579558
```

Comment: That's exactly what I hopped to find. No need to create sub processes just to guess this value (and hope that process IDs are given in sequential order). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I use this under windows but maybe you can try it as a starting point

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen('tasklist')
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x00000268164C3CC0>
>>>
Name                           PID     Session name   No. of s  Utilisation
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
```

this will give you a table which you can capture with

`subprocess.Popen('tasklist').communicate()[0]`, just count the lines and you'll get the current number of processes. Do it again in 1 minute and see what's changed

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually looking at /proc or /sys , let linux do it for you:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

time = 0
ps = subprocess.Popen(["ps",'-A', '-o', 'pid'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
pids = [int(x) for x in ps.communicate()[0].split()[1:]]
new_pids_count = 0;

while time < 60:
    ps = subprocess.Popen(["ps",'-A', '-o', 'pid'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = [int(x) for x in ps.communicate()[0].split()[1:]]
    for x in output:
        if x not in pids:
            new_pids_count += 1
            pids.append(x)
    time += 1
    sleep(1)
```

Initially, I get all the currently running PIDS, using  `ps -A -i -pid`, and put them all in a list. 
I repeat this every second, to check for the newly spawned process, by comparing the results from the running it again, and the growing pids list.

Comment: This works, but does a lot or processing. I would be very happy if I could get the number without checking all processes. But your solution is valid, thank you.